# Core Data removed objects reappearing on startup

Tags: iphone, core-data, object

I have some Core Data entries which are all fetched and thrown into an array when the application starts up.
When I delete an object from Core Data using `deleteObject:` I refresh this array by reading all Core Data entries again and throw them into the array. Here, the Core Data object is correctly deleted and is not loaded into the new array. But when I launch the application again, the entries are not removed. They are loaded again.

Does anyone have an idea why my Core Data objects are not correctly removed?

This is where I delete an object:

```
// Define our table/entity to use  
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Notes" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

// Setup the fetch request  
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entity];

// Fetch the records and handle an error  
NSError *error;  
NSMutableArray *allNotes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy]];

for(int i = 0; i < [allNotes count]; i++) {
    if([[allNotes objectAtIndex:i] identifier] == [[note objectAtIndex:0] identifier]) {
        [managedObjectContext deleteObject:[allNotes objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSLog(@"DELETING..");
        NSLog(@"%@", [allNotes objectAtIndex:i]);
    }
}

[request release];
```

This is how I set the array of Core Data entries on start up

```
// Define our table/entity to use  
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Notes" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext_];

    // Setup the fetch request  
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    // Fetch the records and handle an error  
    NSError *error;  
    globalNotes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[managedObjectContext_ executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy]];

    [request release];

    NSLog(@"NOTES ON STARTUP");
    NSLog(@"%@", globalNotes);
```

Here is some data which I print using `NSLog`. This might help solving the issue and will show, that these notes are deleted but reappers.

```
2011-04-25 20:11:40.877 Caltio[4039:707] NOTES ON STARTUP
2011-04-25 20:11:40.888 Caltio[4039:707] (
    "<Notes: 0x1855d0> (entity: Notes; id: 0x184cd0 <x-coredata://DC8B3294-6D87-4236-9E5C-29E11F7330FA/Notes/p2> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Notes: 0x1858b0> (entity: Notes; id: 0x184ce0 <x-coredata://DC8B3294-6D87-4236-9E5C-29E11F7330FA/Notes/p3> ; data: <fault>)"
)
2011-04-25 20:16:41.561 Caltio[4039:707] DELETING..
2011-04-25 20:16:41.569 Caltio[4039:707] <Notes: 0x1855d0> (entity: Notes; id: 0x184cd0 <x-coredata://DC8B3294-6D87-4236-9E5C-29E11F7330FA/Notes/p2> ; data: {
    added = "2011-04-25 17:56:15 +0000";
    identifier = 2567446185;
    note = Test;
    updated = 0;
})
2011-04-25 20:16:41.589 Caltio[4039:707] NOTES AFTER REFRESH:
2011-04-25 20:16:41.595 Caltio[4039:707] (
    "<Notes: 0x1858b0> (entity: Notes; id: 0x184ce0 <x-coredata://DC8B3294-6D87-4236-9E5C-29E11F7330FA/Notes/p3> ; data: {\n    added = \"2011-04-25 17:57:26 +0000\";\n    identifier = 2567446127;\n    note = Test;\n    updated = 0;\n})"
)

2011-04-25 20:17:05.103 Caltio[4052:707] NOTES ON STARTUP
2011-04-25 20:17:05.115 Caltio[4052:707] (
    "<Notes: 0x1bee60> (entity: Notes; id: 0x1be570 <x-coredata://DC8B3294-6D87-4236-9E5C-29E11F7330FA/Notes/p2> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<Notes: 0x1bf150> (entity: Notes; id: 0x1bdcd0 <x-coredata://DC8B3294-6D87-4236-9E5C-29E11F7330FA/Notes/p3> ; data: <fault>)"
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you save your `managedObjectContext`? As I understand it, adding, amending and deleting objects only really affects their in-memory representation. You also need to save the context to persist it.

Comment: In my AppDelegate, there is a method called `- (void)saveContext` This is added when the project is created. I guess `managedObjectContext` is saved here. I do not do anything besides this. Is there another way I can save it?

Comment: `NSManagedObjectContext` has a method called `save:`. The version of `saveContext` in the app delegate, assuming the one you're referring to is the one in the templates, only saves when the app terminates. Of course, in iOS4 that's almost never.

Comment: That's great! I thought it was saved using `saveContext`. Thank you very much! Well, now I've learned that. Awesome :-)